# Extract simple time data from a string

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have an export of shift data from which I am looking to pull the start and end times so I can create a validation.

Below is a text version of four sample cells from the export. The dates don't matter, just looking to get something like hh:mm-hh:mm out of this.

In Excel I'd probably just do a series of left/right/find by trial and error.

```
Open_115636 09/08/2022 9:30 AM-09/08/2022 6:00 PM
Open_066513 09/08/2022 7:00 AM-09/08/2022 4:00 PM
Open_066513 09/08/2022 8:00 AM-09/08/2022 4:30 PM
Open_115636 09/08/2022 10:00 AM-09/08/2022 6:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5, 
        ".+ (\d+:\d+ \D+-).+ (\d+:\d+ \D+)", "$1$2"))
```

[image]

Comment: That's just about it there, thank you!  If you don't mind, how would you go about forcing the output into 24 hr format? 0930-1800 for example?  Any suggestions for learning more?

Comment: @ChuckJ You need to change your formula to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1GFu.png)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A10, 
 ".+ (\d+:\d+).+(-).+(\d+:\d+) .+", "$1$2$3")))
```

[image]